# Can I Import data into Google Spreadsheet using a Wolfram Cloud API?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, excel, apifunction

I would like to use the `IMPORTDATA` Google Sheets function to load a Wolfram Cloud API into my Spreadsheet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible to do that. Here is a toy code.

```
CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[{}, Function[{}, Table[10 i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 4}]], "CSV"]
 , "csv-test-data", Permissions -> "Public"
 ]
```

> CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/your-user/csv-test-data"]

Then just go to you sheet and use the `IMPORTDATA` function like this:
`=IMPORTDATA("https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/your-user/csv-test-data")`

Voialà! Here is the result

[image]

## Limitation:

- Your data has to be public